# Root element minOccurs or maxOccurs

Tags: xml, xsd

In XSD...

Is it allowed to write beside a root element with minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" ?
like below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

  <xs:element name="shiporder" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        ........
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Was it ever allowed like this in the past ?

Answer (score 0):

**No.**  It would not make sense for `minOccurs` or `maxOccurs` to appear on a [validation root](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#key-vr) because [well-formed XML](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-well-formed) must have a single root element:

> [Definition: There is exactly one element, called the **root**, or
>   document element, no part of which appears in the content of any other
>   element.]

### How to express *optionality* at root level

It is ok to have multiple top-level element declarations, which may be the effect you're after with `minOccurs="0"`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="shiporder">
      ...
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="e2">
      ...
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="e3">
      ...
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

This represents that the root element could be `shiporder` or `e2` or `e3`.

### How to express *multiplicity* at the root level

To allow multiple ship orders, wrap them in a single container, `shiporders`, element:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="shiporders">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="shiporder" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
           ...
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```